# Unity. Работа с UI button

Tags: c#, unity3d

Через что можно реализовать отслеживание зажатия Button? 
Есть UI кнопка и, пока игрок ее держит, происходят действия. Как отпустил — действие прекратилось.
Пробовал через IPointer интерфейсы, но там нет отслеживания зажатия мышки (или — на мобилках — зажатия экрана)

Answer (score 1):

Например, вы можете реализовать наследника `Button`, который даст во вне доступ к нужном методу.

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CustomButton : Button
{
    public new bool IsPressed()
    {
        return base.IsPressed();
    }

}
```

Теперь просто замените компонент `Button` на `CustomButton` везде где нужно.

PS: на самом деле можно реализовать и на `IPointer` интерфейсах:

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CustomButton : Button //, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public bool IsButtonPressed { get; private set; }

    public override void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData){
        base.OnPointerDown(eventData);
        IsButtonPressed = true;
    }

    public override void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData){
        base.OnPointerUp(eventData);
        IsButtonPressed = false;
    }
}
```

НО код в первом примере выглядит красивее и обрабатывает чуть больше возможных ситуаций

Answer (score 0):

Еще вы можете попробовать добавить компонент EventTrigger к вашей кнопке.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]